# Database isn't updated correctly from user input

Tags: c#, sql, database

I've got a page with a calendar where users can add events to. It all works fine apart from one bit where the user can select the language of the event/course. It is being updated in the database, however it seems only the first character of the language value is added to the database so the languages don't display. So for instance if the user selects 'en' only the 'e' is added to the database, or with 'fr' only the 'f'.
This is my code:

```
the mark up:
<asp:DropDownList  Visible="false" class="test-select" ID="ddlLang"  runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddlLang_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select a language" Value="0"> </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="English" Value="en"> </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="French" Value ="fr"></asp:ListItem>                           
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And in the code behind :

```
protected void ddlLang_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    clearForm();
    string UL_ID = ddlLang.SelectedItem.Value;

    if (UL_ID != "0")
    {
        ddlTest1.Visible = true;
        loadTest1DLL(ddlTest2.SelectedItem.Value, UL_ID, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        ddlTest1.SelectedValue = "0";
        ddlTest1.Visible = false;
    }

}

private int AddDate(string[] strArray)
{
    string strQuery = "spInsertDate";
    int iCourseID = 0;
    using (SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection(.......)
    {
        oConn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, oConn))
        {
            oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 150));
            oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nfo_ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4));
            oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Location_ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4));
            oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Language", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
            oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@STARTDATE", SqlDbType.DateTime));
            oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ENDDATE", SqlDbType.DateTime));


            oCmd.Parameters["@Title"].Value = strArray[0];
            oCmd.Parameters["@Info_ID"].Value = strArray[1];
            oCmd.Parameters["@Location_ID"].Value = strArray[2];
            oCmd.Parameters["@Language"].Value = strArray[6];
            oCmd.Parameters["@STARTDATE"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(strArray[3], dtFormat);
            oCmd.Parameters["@ENDDATE"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(strArray[4], dtFormat);

            oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            // Response.Write(DateTime.Parse(strArray[9], dtFormat));
            iCourseCourseID = (int)oCmd.Parameters["@UCSL_ID"].Value;
        }
    }
    return iCourseID;
}

private void UpdateDate(string[] strArray)
{
    string strQuery = "spUpdateDate";
    using (SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection(.........)
    {
        oConn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, oConn))
        {
            oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@STARTDATE", SqlDbType.DateTime));
            oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ENDDATE", SqlDbType.DateTime));
             oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Language", SqlDbType.NVarChar));

            oCmd.Parameters["@STARTDATE"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(strArray[0], dtFormat);
            oCmd.Parameters["@ENDDATE"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(strArray[1], dtFormat);
            oCmd.Parameters["@Location_ID"].Value = strArray[3];
            oCmd.Parameters["@Language"].Value = strArray[5];

            oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone spot what I've missed and why this happens? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
 int iCheckCourseModule = 0;
        if (iCheckCourseModule == 0)
        {
            int iDateId = AddDate(strArray);
            lblMsgBox.CssClass = "sucessLabel";
            lblMsgBox.Text = "Course Date Created Sucessfully";
            clearForm();
            loadCourseDatesInfo(strUCSID);
        }
```

Comment: What is the language column definition and size? possible 1?

Comment: Can you show the code that calls AddDate and therefore how string[] strArray is populated?

Comment: Can you also confirm if the problem is happening in the insert, the update or both?

Comment: @sagi it's nvarchar(2) so that shouldn't be the issue

Comment: You didn't specify a `Size` for your `@Language` parameter.

Comment: Debug and see if correct value is being passed to sp,  also size of variable in sp collecting language value.

Comment: Debug and see if correct value is being passed to sp,  also size of variable in sp collecting language value.

Comment: I don't see where you are adding a `@Language` parameter to the `spUpdateDate` command.

Comment: Check your length definitions *everywhere*. On the SQL Side, any variable/parameter declared as `nvarchar` rather than `nvarchar(length)` defaults to a length of 1.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks, the issue was in one of the stored procedures where the nvarchar was set to default